# How to prompt user for a password to use an application in Mac?

Tags: mac, passwords, keychain

Is there a way to prompt the user for a password when he or she tries to open a given application? And is there a way to set that to something different than the user account password? I want it to not simply authorize the user, but also prevent someone who might know my account password to not be able to reuse that to gain access to the application.

EDIT: I would prefer a free solution, but if need be, I can pay for something.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try the App Espionage? http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/29384/espionage

You can save the application inside a certain folder and protect it with Espionage app.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Would you happen to know of any completely free solutions though?

Comment: You can try to make a disk image out of a folder using the built in disk utility.
    Open up the “Disk Utility” application
    File -> New -> Disk Image from Folder…
    choose a folder to protect
    choose “AES-128″ encryption and press Save
    Enter your desired new password twice.
The disk image contains the entire contents of the folder, but cannot be opened unless the correct password is supplied. A password dialog box will appear once you open the disk image. Once you supply your correct password, Finder will automatically unencrypt your data and mount the image as a disk.